# How to connect to a network folder?

Tags: powershell

How to connect to a network folder without connecting a disk? I need to connect to a folder, archive it, and then save this archive to another folder. And do it every 15 minutes.

```
$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
$net.MapNetworkDrive("W:", "\\server\share", $false, "Username", "password")
$date1 = Get-Date -Date "01/01/1970"
$date2 = Get-Date
$d = (New-TimeSpan -Start $date1 -End $date2).TotalSeconds
$compress = @{
  Path = "W:\"
  CompressionLevel = "Fastest"
  DestinationPath = "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Folder\archive-" + $d + ".zip"
}
Compress-Archive @compress
```

Comment: easiest way: cron + ssh + scp

Comment: Up can upload file using FTP.

Comment: What happens if you use `Path = '\\server\share'` as the parameter to `Compress-Archive`? Alternatively, have you tried `New-PSDrive`?